# My inbox isn't working right

Tags: bug, notifications, global-inbox

Every time I come to Stack Exchange and I have inbox items, I click on the inbox icon and all I see are repeated reminders of the long-closed community moderator elections, and I can't even scroll in the box to find the actual replies I care about. Instead, I have to go to a subsite to actually see the incoming messages; once I do that my inbox starts to display correctly again on Stack Exchange.